# Sentence beginning with "Between [year] and [year] "

Tags: commas, prepositional-phrases, sentence-starts

I’ve just been told it is wrong to put a comma after an “introductory time period”, for example:
“Between 1990 and 2003, diligent seekers found hundreds of incorrectly placed commas in all manner of texts.”

Is this really a hard and fast rule?
If the sentence were very short, I might agree there's no need for a comma, but in the actual case (of which my sample above is an approximation), I see no need to delete it. But the editor has added a note indicating that the comma actually violates a rule, and I'd like to get that confirmed (if it is true).

Looking forward to your comments, thanks!

Comment: Ask your editor which style guide they adhere to. [Some guides](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/punctuation/commas/commas_after_introductions.html)  say that after an introductory prepositional phrase it is wrong. Others say it is optional.

Comment: It's a soft and slow rule.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input!
Cascabel, the guide at your link (Purdue U. writing lab) doesn't say it's wrong, it just says not to use it after a very short introductory prepositional phrase (5 words or less) – which would, of course, apply in this case.
Hot Licks, are you saying that it's a rule for some, but not one that all recognize? Something like that? Or are you just making a joke? (sorry, it's hard to tell sometimes without seeing facial expressions)

Comment: There is no real right and wrong with punctuation...there are style guidelines. Ask your editor which style guide they prefer.